# Get the file causing linker error in g++

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I am building a binary which uses multiple components which are compiled as .so files. I am getting a flurry of linker errors which point to which .so file caused them, but can I get information about which files are calling undefined functions or if possible source code locations where undefined functions are being called? I am finding it too tedious to hunt down the function esp since lot of overloading and templates are being used (which means same name in many places). In windows, it shows which .o file caused the undefined symbol, but am stuck at the level of libraries in linux. I use g++ in linux. Any pointer would be useful.

Comment: Why not skip the library step? Instead of combining the objects into libraries and loading them dynamically, link the objects directly into the binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking "which object file inside a shared library is causing the error".

The problem is that by the time that shared library has been linked, all object files have been "fused together", and no longer exist inside the shared library as separate entities, so your question is somewhat meaningless.

That said, if you do a debug build (with `-g` flag), the linker will tell you which *source* file and line is causing the problem, which you then may be able to translate into the object file.

If you can't (e.g. because the problem symbol is referenced in a header file), you can ask the linker for help: rebuild the library again, passing the linker `-y` flag:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared ${OBJECTS} -o foo.so -Wl,-y,my_unresolved_symbol
```

will tell you which object(s) reference `my_unresolved_symbol`.

Note: linker operates "below" C++, so you must pass the mangled name, e.g. `_Znw` to it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it was very useful. I also just managed to tweak the build system to produce static libraries instead of dynamic ones and now gcc gives the information I want.

Answer (score 0):

With [`ldd`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ldd.htm) (print shared library dependencies) you can check the dependencies of an so and if they are resolved or not.

With the use of [`nm -Aa --demangle`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm) you can get a list of symbols used or defined in an *.so file, as long as they were not stripped away. The used symbols should at least remain, so that you can check if there are some unresolved symbols.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know from the error message which so file causes the error. I would like to know which object file inside it uses the undefined function